# Casting array to type

Tags: typescript, types, interface, casting

```
interface player_info {
    local: number,
    client_id: number,
    team: number,
    score: number,
    latency: number
}
```

Is it possible to cast an array to the interface?
So, e.g. if I have the array `[1,2,3,4,5]`, it would get casted into the type `{local: 1, client_id: 2, team: 3, score: 4, latency: 5}`

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have "casting", or at least nothing with any runtime effect.  You have to write your own conversion function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NlpAXN) to get that behavior.   If that meets your needs I can write up an answer; if not, please elaborate on what use cases it fails to satisfy.

Comment: I mean that works too, but since this is only one example of many interfaces (which i forgot to mention), it would be kinda ugly to do that for every interface

Comment: Which is worse: ugly or impossible?  There are possibly extra build tools that could process your TypeScript code to give you what you want, but that’s not part of TypeScript itself. Interfaces are completely erased from the runtime code so there’s nothing to consult when you call `convert([1,2,3,4,5])`. It’s possible you can define your interfaces in terms of some other structure which does make it to runtime, but that’s reversing the question.

Comment: At the very least you will need an array of keys somewhere for each interface, so that the runtime knows which properties should go where (object types do not have key ordering; `{foo: string, bar: string}` and `{bar: string, foo: string}` are identical types.  So something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w11KYw) is possible and might be less awful than writing it out manually for each interface.  Would you be interested in that as an answer? Or are you still looking for something else (and if so, you might want to [edit] your question to specify it)